# VS Code ставит на паузу все сеансы отладки go при установке брейкпоинта, как это отключить?

Tags: golang, visual-studio-code

Если я запускаю один или несколько процессов отладки кода golang и затем поставлю в каком угодно файле брейкпоинт(в том числе и в файлах другого языка), то все сеансы отладки автоматически становятся на паузу и их нужно вручную продолжать. Это очень сильно разражает, особенно если запускаю несколько процессов. Как это отключить?

Comment: может просто убрать брейкпоинт или запускать, а не дебажить

Comment: Совет запускать, а не дебажить довольно странный, ведь мне нужно именно дебажить. В 2022 возвращаться к дебагу через log.Print очень странно. Насчет убрать брейкпоинт не совсем понимаю что вы имеете ввиду, может я объяснил непонятно. Допустим, у меня запущено 2 проекта go в режиме дебага, все работает нормально. Я ставлю в произвольном месте брейкпоинт(допустим, в соседней папке с кодом на js) - оба процесса дебага стали на паузу(не на брейкпоинте, он в файле js) и не продолжат выполнение, пока не сниму. Склоняюсь к тому, что это баг и буду готовить баг-репорт

Answer (score 0):

Решилось переходом на legacy адаптер delve. В настройках нужно добавить:

```
"go.delveConfig": {
    "debugAdapter": "legacy"
}
```